# "Hello, World!" (Every other character, Part 2)

Tags: code-golf, source-layout, hello-world

As a kind of part 2 to [Hello, World! (Every other character)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128496/hello-world-every-other-character?noredirect=1#comment319193_128496), write a program such that **all three** of these programs print "Hello, World!": the entire program, the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc. characters of your program, *and* the 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc.

If your program is:

```
abc
def
```

It should output "Hello, World!", but so should

```
acdf
```

**And**

```
b
e
```

No solutions with built-in "Hello, World!"s.

Comment: Why not just change the text from "Hello, World!" to something else?

Comment: I think that avoids loopholes enough and "Hello, World!" is canonical.

Comment: IMO it'd be nice to see a different string than "Hello, World!" once in a while (that's just my opinion)

Comment: Are whitespaces and newlines counted as characters?

Comment: @officialaimm Yes.

Comment: Odd/even keeper https://jsfiddle.net/d71x6ah7/6/

Comment: @ConorO'Brien With the pleasant side effect that very few languages will have built-ins for literally every other string.

Comment: Why are builtins banned here but not on Part 1?

Comment: Why exactly was this marked as a duplicate?

Comment: Because many programming languages ignore leading whitespace, so an answer to the duplicate could be made an answer to this one by adding or removing a leading space.

Comment: @ppperry I think you misunderstood something in the question. The original question was just the full program and the odd characters, but this one is the full program, the even characters, and the odd characters. This makes it much harder to find a solution. For example, in the original question, since many golfing languages ignore spaces, you could just do a regular hello world, but with spaces in between each letter. In part 2, this wouldn't work.

Comment: Oh, I did. That wasn't very clear.

Comment: @ppperry Thanks for the feedback. I've clarified my question.

Answer (score 24):

## x86 machine code, 378 bytes

[image: demo]

**PROG.COM** [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/glcf3qm4n2vmuoq/PROG.COM?dl=1) and run it in **MS-DOS** emulator, [DOSBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSBox) for example.

```
B3 B4 B3 02 90 B3 B3 B4 02 B3 B4 B3 02 90 B3 B2
B3 48 90 B3 B3 B2 48 B3 B2 B3 48 90 B3 CD B3 21
90 B3 B3 CD 21 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 B2 B3 65 90 B3
B3 B2 65 B3 B2 B3 65 90 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 B3 CD
21 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 B2 B3 6C 90 B3 B3 B2 6C B3
B2 B3 6C 90 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 B3 CD 21 B3 CD B3
21 90 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 B3 CD 21 B3 CD B3 21 90
B3 B2 B3 6F 90 B3 B3 B2 6F B3 B2 B3 6F 90 B3 CD
B3 21 90 B3 B3 CD 21 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 B2 B3 2C
90 B3 B3 B2 2C B3 B2 B3 2C 90 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3
B3 CD 21 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 B2 B3 20 90 B3 B3 B2
20 B3 B2 B3 20 90 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 B3 CD 21 B3
CD B3 21 90 B3 B2 B3 77 90 B3 B3 B2 77 B3 B2 B3
77 90 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 B3 CD 21 B3 CD B3 21 90
B3 B2 B3 6F 90 B3 B3 B2 6F B3 B2 B3 6F 90 B3 CD
B3 21 90 B3 B3 CD 21 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 B2 B3 72
90 B3 B3 B2 72 B3 B2 B3 72 90 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3
B3 CD 21 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 B2 B3 6C 90 B3 B3 B2
6C B3 B2 B3 6C 90 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 B3 CD 21 B3
CD B3 21 90 B3 B2 B3 64 90 B3 B3 B2 64 B3 B2 B3
64 90 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 B3 CD 21 B3 CD B3 21 90
B3 B2 B3 21 90 B3 B3 B2 21 B3 B2 B3 21 90 B3 CD
B3 21 90 B3 B3 CD 21 B3 CD B3 21 90 B3 CD B3 20
90 B3 B3 CD 20 B3 CD B3 20 90
```

Also you can download [LEFT.COM](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2kgco8zi2kjlnx/LEFT.COM?dl=1) and [RIGHT.COM](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmwrx4mixbbrz23/RIGHT.COM?dl=1)

### How it works and how to run

[See answer to part one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129328/71612)

### Magic

If you want to execute **0xAB** opcode command with one parameter **0xCD**, you write

[image: Magic]

### Generator

Run code, get hex. Convert in to binary

```
cat prog.hex | xxd -r -p > PROG.COM
```

```js
function byte2hex(byte){
 var ret=byte.toString(16).toUpperCase();
 return ret.length==1 ? "0"+ret : ret;
}

function str2hex(str){
 var ret = [];
 for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
  ret.push(byte2hex(str.charCodeAt(i)));
 }
 return ret;
}

function genCode(hexArr){
 var ret = [["B4","02"]];
 for(var i=0;i<hexArr.length;i++){
  if(hexArr[i]!=hexArr[i-1]){
   ret.push(["B2",hexArr[i]]);
  }
  ret.push(["CD","21"]);
 }
 ret.push(["CD","20"]);

 return ret;
}

function format(arr){
 var ret=[],tmp=[];
 for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  tmp.push(arr[i]);
  if(i%16==15 || i==arr.length-1){ret.push(tmp.join(" "));tmp=[];}
 }
 return ret.join("\n");
}

function magicCode(str,mode){
 var ret=[];
 var code=genCode(str2hex(str));

 for(var i=0;i<code.length;i++){
  var ab=code[i][0],cd=code[i][1],tmp;
  tmp=["B3",ab,"B3",cd,"90","B3","B3",ab,cd,"B3",ab,"B3",cd,"90"];
  for(var j=0;j<tmp.length;j++){
   if((mode&1 && j%2==0) || (mode&2 && j%2==1)){ret.push(tmp[j])}
  }
  
 }
 return ret;
}

const LEFT=1,RIGHT=2,ALL=3;

var str=prompt("string","Hello, world!");

var out = ["PROG.COM\n",format(magicCode(str,ALL)),"\n\nLEFT.COM\n",format(magicCode(str,LEFT)),"\n\nRIGHT.COM\n",format(magicCode(str,RIGHT))].join("\n");

document.write(out.replace(/\n/ig,"<br>"));
```

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 115 bytes

```python
print=="partisn't";
"ran" >="partisn't" ;
print((""" "HHeelllloo,,  wwoorrlldd!! """[" ) #2">"1":: 3- 1] [ 1:-1 ]))
```

#### Every odd character

```python
pit=print;"a">"ats'";pit(" Hello, world! "[  2>1: -1  :1])
```

#### Every even character

```python
rn="ats'"
rn =print 
rn("""Hello, world!""")#""":3 ][1- )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY2xCoMwGIR3n@L8O8SADtEtEmffQTJIDVQISUgC2qdPRUrpLcd3d3DhnV/eDSVBgTFWQtxdVorCGvOeHMs0VhRXR5j@Q4zVvWwaIgLNszH2kvdtCxyH9zFau211jatfCByPniYSJCWGDkJjgZCdgOa8XL@VOc2zSfzri5S9/oG4qXwA)

This could probably get a lot shorter, but I'm happy I managed to get it to work in Python. Similar to [vroomfondel's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128524/63641) on the first part.

## Boring 93 byte answer

```python
""""""
print("Hello, world!")
""""""#
""""

pprriinntt((""HHeelllloo,,  wwoorrlldd!!""))
#"""
```

#### Every odd character

```python
"""pit"el,wrd"
"""
""
print("Hello, world!")#"
```

#### Every even character

```python
"""
rn(Hlo ol!)"""#""
print("Hello, world!")
""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY0xCkMhEET7PcW6v1DBJkn3Ib13CKmiEEFc2S@YnN6ICZnmMcwMU9/tyeUyDryi1nrQElRJpRnyMWd22FlyUGThm26LALWKpFRKa8YQeR9ne/bZOcTemUVyDkEpImthm5MxHyC@4sMc9sfbvp/vf3NabnwA)

Answer (score 9):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 45 bytes

```
! """!!ddllrrooWW  oolllleeHH"!!"" >~o <> o <
```

Or just even characters:

```
 "!dlroW olleH"!">o<
```

Or just odd characters:

```
!""!dlroW olleH!" ~ >o<
```

Try them online: [original](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X1FBSUlJUTElJSenqCg/PzxcQSE/PwcIUlM9PIASSkoKdnX5CjZ2CkDi/38A), [evens](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0FJMSWnKD9cIT8nJ9VDSVHJLt9GQeH/fwA), [odds](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X1FJSTElpyg/XCE/JyfVQ1FJoU7BLt/m/38A).

The original version pushes "`!!ddllrrooWW  oolllleeHH`" to the stack, then the fish bounces between `>~o <`, which deletes a letter, prints two, deletes two, prints two, deletes two, etc. The two half-programs are fairly standard string printing programs. The tricky part was combining `"` and `!` to toggle in and out of string mode in all three programs correctly.

Answer (score 7):

### [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 43 bytes

```
120 x""!!ddllrrooWW  ,,oolllleeHH""cckk,,@@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/39DIQKFCSUlRMSUlJ6eoKD8/PFxBQUcnPz8HCFJTPTyUlJKTs7N1dBwc/v8HAA)

Only the odd ones:

```
10x"!dlroW ,olleH"ck,@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/39CgQkkxJacoP1xBJz8nJ9VDKTlbx@H/fwA)

Only the even ones:

```
2 "!dlroW ,olleH"ck,@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/30hBSTElpyg/XEEnPycn1UMpOVvH4f9/AA)

#### Explanation

The full program:

```
120               Push 1, push 2, push 0.
x                 Pop 0 (y) and 2 (x) and set the instruction pointer's movement
                  delta to (x,y). That is, run the remainder of the code
                  by skipping every other cell.
"!dlroW ,olleH"   Push the code points of the output.
ck,               Print 13 characters from the top of the stack.
@                 Terminate the program.
```

In the odd program, the `2` is gone, so that `10x` really does nothing at all (it sets the delta to `(1,0)` which is the default anyway). The remainder of the program is then the same.

In the even program, we just push the `2` at the beginning which we can ignore entirely. The remainder of the program is the same as before.

Answer (score 6):

## [Gammaplex](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Gammaplex), 46 bytes

```
//

EERRrrXXXX""HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!""XX
```

[See here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85034/25180)

[Interpreter.](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/gammaplex/impl/gammaplex.zip) It may need some changes to work in modern compilers.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 65 bytes

```
PPrriinntt[[""HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!""]]Print@"Hello, World!"
```

It throws some warnings, prints `Hello, World!`, and returns `Null PPrriinntt[["" HHeelllloo, Null, "" WWoorrlldd!!]]`. When run as a program (not in the REPL), the return value will not be printed.

After removing the even characters:

```
Print["Hello, World!"]Pit"el,Wrd"
```

It prints `Hello, World!`, and returns `"el,Wrd" Null Pit`.

After removing the odd characters:

```
Print["Hello, World!"]rn@Hlo ol!
```

It prints `Hello, World!`, and returns `Null ol! rn[Hlo]`.

Answer (score 5):

### x86 machine code, 73 bytes

Inspired by *Евгений Новиков*'s solution, I thought it should be doable with less tricks, i.e., just jumping around to otherwise "disjoint" codes for all three variants. I'm still trying with a smart variant that uses `lodsb; lodsb` as central point (so only one string constant is needed for all variants)

```
EB 14 00 00 8A 8A 17 16 01 01 B4 B4 09 09 CD CD
21 21 CD CD 20 20 8A 1f 01 B4 09 CD 21 CD 20 48
65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21 00 48 48 65
65 6c 6c 6c 6c 6f 6f 2c 2c 20 20 57 57 6f 6f 72
72 6c 6c 64 64 21 21 00 00
```

If I recall correctly from my childhood days, COM's tiny model starts with `DS=CS=SS` and the code is loaded beginning from `CS:0100h`. I do not assume it is guaranteed that the code is loaded into a zeroed memory block (if it were guaranteed, I could drop two bytes).

Disassembly of the long code should be

```
  JMP *+14h
  ; 20 irrelevant bytes
  MOV DX,message
  MOV AH,09h
  INT 21h;  print string pointed to by DS:DX
  INT 20h;  exit program
message:
  DB "Hello, World!\0"
  DB "HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!\0\0"
```

Disassembly of odd code

```
  JMP *+00h
  MOV DX,message
  MOV AH,09h
  INT 21h;  print string pointed to by DS:DX
  INT 20h;  exit program
  ; some irrelevant bytes
message:
  DB "Hello, World!\0"
```

Disassembly of even code:

```
  ADC AL,00h
  MOV DX,message
  MOV AH,09h
  INT 21h;  print string pointed to by DS:DX
  INT 20h;  exit program
  ; some irrelevant bytes
message:
  DB "Hello, World!\0"
```

Comment: Good job! In DOSBox program is not working. I don't know why com file with this code freeze system at start.

Comment: Test your code next time. The `8A` at 0116 should be `BA` instead, and strings are terminated by `$`, not NULL.

Answer (score 4):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 48 bytes

```
G |`

HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!
$_&

(.)\1t?
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fXaEmgYvLwyM1NQcI8vN1dBQUwsPz84uKcnJSUhQVuVTi1bi4NPQ0YwxL7LlUDP//BwA)

Odd positions:

```
G|
Hello, World!
_
()1?$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fvYbLIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFkSueS0PT0F7l/38A)

Even positions:

```
 `
Hello, World!$&
.\t
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fIYHLIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFUUWNSy@mhMvw/38A)

#### Explanation

**The full program:**

```
G |`
```

This does nothing at all. The `|` is not an existing configuration option. The `G` makes this a grep stage, but there is really nothing to be grepped and the regex is empty any, so this doesn't do anything. The purpose of this stage is to have two linefeeds in front of the main "Hello, World!" line so that one of them always survives the reduction. The reason for making this a grep stag is that we need to offset the parity of the lines, and grep stages only require a single line.

```
HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!
```

This turns the (empty) working string into the required output with each character doubled.

```
$_&
```

This does nothing. The regex tries to match a `_` and a `&` after the end of the string which is of course impossible. We'll need those characters in the reduced version though, again to deal with vanishing linefeeds.

```
(.)\1t?
$1
```

Finally, we remove the duplicate characters by replacing `(.)\1` with `$1`. The `t?` is never used but will again be necessary in the reduced versions.

**The odd program:**

```
G|
Hello, World!
```

The `G` can't match the empty input, but that's why we have the `|` to allow an alternative empty match. This turns the empty working string into the desired output.

```
_
()1?$
```

This replaces underscores with `()1?$`, but there are no underscores in the string, so this does nothing.

**The even program:**

```
 `
Hello, World!$&
```

The `` ` `` just denotes an empty configuration string, so we again use the empty regex to replace the working string with the output. This time we also insert `$&` but that's the match itself, which is empty, of course, so it doesn't do anything.

```
.\t
1
```

This would replace any character followed by a tab with a `1`, but we don't have any tabs, so this is also a no-op.

Answer (score 4):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 106 bytes

```lua
----[[[[
print("Hello, World!")
--[[
---- ] ]
---- ] ]
pprriinntt((""HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!""))
----]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYsxCsAgDEV3TxEzKdh7eAOH4lCwgxCMBHv@NHbpmz789@i5VA/jNNyUPlbAfBNxgsJCzWN0@3Vbggr1H3OK9D7GWiEg5nxbZiGnBFAKswhRa94jxvhVtaq@)

Alternate 1:

```lua
--[[
rn(Hlo ol!)-[
--]]--  
print("Hello, World!")--]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P9fVzc6mqsoT8MjJ18hP0dRUzeaS1c3NlZXV0GBq6AoM69EQ8kjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRSRMo/f8/AA)

Alternate #2:

```lua
--[[pit"el,Wrd"
-[--  
--]]print("Hello, World!")
--]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P9fVzc6uiCzRCk1Rye8KEWJSzdaV1dBgUtXNza2oCgzr0RDySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVFJEyT1/z8A)

Alternator script: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYvBCsMgEETvfoXZk4INtL0FevcPPAQPBYUuWFdWL/l6Y0JL5rDMzswrW/tQfvaO30LcZN2qwNe4c20B88zxHZQWhTE3heuyPPz/u9L7Gfd@G1qHfgXYmBIZ6YhTmECLoxXHSHrpL1MKM2LOrSkFYG0c2ADJGCmdI2JOKYRpAtD6pLzfAQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 44 bytes

```
{{HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!}}ss{{}}ss-X)%L-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7rawyM1NQcI8vN1dBQUwsPz84uKcnJSUhQVa2uLi6urQaRuhKaqj@7//wA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), 36 bytes

```
vv^^vv""!!ddllrrooWW  ,,oolllleeHH""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/7@sLC6urExJSVExJSUnp6goPz88XEFBRyc/PwcIUlM9PJSU/v8HAA)

Every other character (in both ways):

```
v^v"!dlroW ,olleH"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/78srkxJMSWnKD9cQSc/JyfVQ@n/fwA)

#### How it works

Backhand's IP starts at the first character and bounces back and forth, skipping certain number of steps at once. The initial step size is 3, which can be adjusted with `^` (increase) and `v` (decrease) commands.

```
vv^^vv""!!ddllrrooWW  ,,oolllleeHH""
v                                     decrease step size to 2
  ^                                   increase step size to 3
     v                                decrease step size to 2
       " ! d l r o W   , o l l e H "  push the string
                                 H    halt and print the string

v^v"!dlroW ,olleH"
v                   decrease step size to 2
  v                 decrease step size to 1
   "!dlroW ,olleH"  push the string
                H   halt and print the string
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 70 bytes

```
"";echo'Hello, World!'.""//pprriinntt''HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!''
;;
```

Odd characters:

```
";coHlo ol!."/print'Hello, World!';
```

Even characters:

```
"eh'el,Wrd'"/print'Hello, World!'
;
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 92 bytes

```hs
{---- }

mmaaiinn==ppuuttSSttrr""HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!""----}main=putStr"Hello, World!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcshDsAgDEBRv1NANTsCHo9Ak0AyskJJV9TC2Rn7@v0rPndGXOs9d2oeR60xltKatb2PIeK9CDOAc3lDRCJjlAqBiBkxJa0B/nfWWJrtQ7wwuE3JqECMScNaHw) It looks like the comment abuse is too much for the syntax highlighting to handle. `{- ... -}` is an inline or multi-line comment, whereas `--` starts a line comment.

**Odd characters:**

```hs
{--}
main=putStr"Hello, World!"--mi=uSrHlo ol!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v1pXt5YrNzEzz7agtCS4pEjJAyicr6MQnl@Uk6KopKubm2lbGlzkkZOvkJ@j@P8/AA)

**Even characters:**

```hs
-- 
main=putStr"Hello, World!"--}anptt"el,Wrd"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/X1dXgSs3MTPPtqC0JLikSMkDKJqvoxCeX5SToqikq1ubmFdQUqKUmqMTXpSi9P8/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 54 bytes

```sh
<<<Hello\ world!||eecchhoo  HHeelllloo\\  wwoorrlldd!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBBa8MwDIXv@hUvJZ3bwy49Zia3ltz6B3IJtloHjDXssEDb/fbMztigVBch3nufhG7JLS0kjtcxDB5aQx3PJ7VorTv2XnrMEr2tHg9mY5wTAbqOs5RF6XtgnkVi9N7aqlpyloguEiHWgr84YAyo77vUNPtNvdN/m/ab7w9YIeT6jGOYLlDbpFCXHNq25F/FFZjF0slKYCIzTGjfDnjPt@fjzzlu3BAHM3FMjVo5z55a9eFYQE@@FcnGSXES3ZL7/8rvkDmlF9/yAw)

The main program executes the first statement successfully, so the statement after the boolean `||` is ignored.

For odd/even, the `<<<Hello\ world!` becomes either an unterminated `<<heredoc` or a `<file` provided on stdin. Either way, the `||` becomes `|`, and so whatever is output by the first command is piped into and ignored by `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

### [LOGO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fmslogo/), 71 bytes

```
;;\\
pr[Hello, World!]er "|

pprr[[HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!]]
;;\\
|
```

(the program have a trailing newline)

Two removed versions:

```
;\p[el,Wrd]r"
pr[Hello, World!]
;\|
```

and

```
;\
rHlo ol!e |
pr[Hello, World!];\
```

(the program have a trailing newline)

For an explanation what `pr` and `er` do, see [this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128496/hello-world-every-other-character/129428#129428). In this case, `er` is feed with a word determine procedure name.

The `\` is escape character in Logo, which will escape the newline after the end of the comment, therefore make the second line (`rHlo ol!e |`) of second removed program a comment.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript,68 bytes

```
//**
alert`Hello, World`//**//aalleerrtt``HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd``
```

Odd Characters:

```
/*aetHlo ol`/*/alert`Hello, World`
```

Even Characters:

```
/*
lr`el,Wrd/*/alert`Hello, World`
```

Modified version of my answer on the other one.

Comment: Why do you need the space at the start?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be syntactically valid when you take the 1st, 3rd, etc. characters. Also, it's missing a `l` in `HHeelllloo`.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline,@Arnauld fixed

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 61 bytes

**60 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```perl
$ _ =$ _ =q";HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!";;;q##;s/;|.\K.//g##
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FIV7BFkwUKll7eKSm5gBBfr6OjoJCeHh@flFRTk5KiqKikrW1daGysnWxvnWNXoy3nr5@urLy//9c//ILSjLz84r/6xYAAA)

#### Every Odd Byte

```perl
  $_="Hello, World!";q#s;.K/g#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19BQSXeVskjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRybpQudhaz1s/Xfn/f65/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

#### Every Even Byte

```perl
$_=  q;Hello, World!;;#;/|\./#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZBodDaIzUnJ19HITy/KCdF0dpa2Vq/JkZPX/n/f65/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [BotEngine](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Bot-Engine), <s>180</s> 178 bytes

Based on my answer to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128496/hello-world-every-other-character/156834#156834) question.

```
 vv 
 v < 
 eHH 
 eee 
 ell 
 ell 
 eoo 
 e,, 
 e   
 eWW 
 eoo 
 err 
 ell 
 edd 
 e!! 

>>P          e     e     e     e     e     e     e     e     e     e     e     e     e P
```

Odd characters (note the multiple trailing spaces on the last line):

```
 v
v<
eH
ee
el
el
eo
e,
e 
eW
eo
er
el
ed
e!
>P
```

Even characters:

```
v     H  e  l  l  o  ,     W  o  r  l  d  ! 
>     e  e  e  e  e  e  e  e  e  e  e  e  eP
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 52 bytes

```
 L @""H!edlllroo,W  W,oorlllde!H"" ~@"!dlroW ,olleH"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/1/BR8FBSclDMTUlJyenKD9fJ1xBIVwnP78IyE1JVfRQUlKoc1BSTAHKhSvo5OfkpHoo/f8PAA)

Runic is not usually very good at dealing with radiation as having flow control characters removed at random makes tracing execution a huge pain, but predictable radiation like every other character? Easy, we just encode two programs that are reversed of each other and interleaved, then tack on a third copy for the base execution and control which one is executed with a single character. In program 2, the third copy is garbage that's never seen, and in program 3 it retains the quotes, allowing it to be popped without printing it.

Program 1 only executes this part:

```
 L                                  @"!dlroW ,olleH"
```

Program 2 only executes this part:

```
    " H e l l o ,   W o r l d ! "   @
```

Like this:

```
  "Hello, World!" @!lo olH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/19BQckjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRScFBMSdfIT/H4/9/AA)

Program 3 only executes this part:

```
 L @ " ! d l r o W   , o l l e H " ~ " d r W , l e "
```

Like this:

```
L@"!dlroW ,olleH"~"drW,le"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/9/HQUkxJacoP1xBJz8nJ9VDqU4ppShcJydV6f9/AA)

The `"drW,le"` portion is executed, but the `~` immediately pops it off the stack, preserving the desired output.

Naively it would appear that a conversion of the ><> answer would result in a shorter program, weighing in at 45 bytes:

````
! ```!!ddllrrooWW  oolllleeHH`!!`` R~$ LR $ L
````

However, Runic has one limitation that ><> does not have: a maximum stack size of 10 + IP's mana (which is initially 10). And `!!ddllrrooWW  oolllleeHH` contains 24 characters, causing the IP to bleed mana until it expires just before executing the `R` command, resulting in no output for the base program.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/19RISEhQVExJSUnp6goPz88XEEhPz8HCFJTPTyAEgkJCkF1Kgo@QQpAwvr/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 33 bytes

```
\` ð`HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!`√
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5C%60%20%C3%B0%60HHeelllloo%2C%2C%20%20WWoorrlldd!!%60%E2%88%9A&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
`ðHello, World!`
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%C3%B0Hello%2C%20World!%60&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
\ `Hello, World!√
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5C%20%60Hello%2C%20World!%E2%88%9A&inputs=&header=&footer=)

These all exploit the bug/feature that single special characters in strings are ignored during parsing.

```
\`                                # Push a backtick (useless)
   ð                              # Push a space (useless)
    `HHeelllloo,,  WWoorrlldd!!`  # String literal
                                √ # Get every second character
```

```
` Hello, World!` # String literal
 ð               # Single non-ascii character (ignored)
```

```
\                 # Push a space
  `Hello, World!  # String literal (unterminated)
                √ # Single non-ascii character - ignored
```